# Exception while executing Tell method in Akka

Tags: f#, agent, akka.net

I am using Akka.net (version="1.0.8") .I have two Actors one is reading Input from database and other is accepting that input and contains some processing logic. Actor “A” is Input actor and “B” is actor for processing input.
When we send around 50 000 messages (size around 30kb each) to “actor B”
for ex.

```
[1..10000000]
|> List.iter(fun msg -> 
actRef.Tell(JsonConvert.SerializeObject(ProcessData (MessageData))))
```

I get below errors with some dead letters:

```
    “[WARNING][4/29/2016 10:08:18 AM][Thread 0009]
    [[akka://Pankaj/system/endpointManager/reliableEndpointWriterakka.tcp%3a%2f%2fRemoteFSharp%40***.**.**.**%3a8788-1]] 
    Association with remote system akka.tcp://RemoteFSharp@***.**.**.**:8788 has failed; 
    address is now gated for 5000 ms. 
    Reason is: [Akka.Remote.EndpointDisassociatedException: Disassociated …
    [INFO]
    [4/29/2016 10:08:18 AM][Thread 0021][akka://Pankaj/deadLetters] 
    Message String from akka://Pankaj/deadLetters to akka://Pankaj/deadLetters was not delivered. 
    1 dead letters encountered… “”
```

But when I use Ask method it works fine.

```
[1..1000000]
|> List.iter(fun msg -> 
   actRef.Ask(JsonConvert.SerializeObject(ProcessData (MessageData))).Wait())
```

If I put a delay of 10ms before every Tell call then I get some error after processing 200 000 records.

Wwhat exactly I am missing here?
What is the dead letter exception and how to fix it?

Comment: could you display body of receiving actor? this can be an issue when you have a long process inside receive method and not use stacking

Comment: @profesor79 I have mentioned some more and clear details on other thread :  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/37000628/data-being-lost-while-sending-messages-form-one-actor-to-another