# Data being lost while sending messages form one actor to another

Tags: f#, actor, akka.net

I have created an Agent say "A", which simply sends some bulky data to Agent "B".

Agent A Code :

```
let largeText = "some large text (around 30kb)"
InputData_Type =
{
 //some code
  Body : string
}

let default_InputData =
{
   //some code
    Body = largeText 
}
type ActorMsg =
| InItServices
| Data of InputData_Type
| UpdateList
let system = ActorSystem.Create("A") 
let actRef = system.ActorSelection("akka.tcp://B@localhost:9999/user/EchoServer")
actRef.Ask(JsonConvert.SerializeObject(InItServices)).Wait()

[1..1000000]
|> List.iter(fun  x -> 
                     actRef.Tell(JsonConvert.SerializeObject(Data (default_InputData))))

let listLength = string(actRef.Ask(JsonConvert.SerializeObject(UpdateList)).Result)

printfn "length is %A" listLength
```

Agent "B" is stores/maintains the data he received into a database.

Agent B code :

```
try
   let echoServer = 
        spawn system "EchoServer"
        <| fun mailbox ->
            let rec loop( cnt : int32 ) =
                actor {
                let! message = mailbox.Receive()
                let sender = mailbox.Sender()
                let deserializedEmailData = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<ActorMsg> (message)

                match deserializedEmailData with
                | InItServices  ->
                    sender <! ""
                    return! loop (0)

                | Data (textData)-> 
                    // some logic to maintain list
                    let count = cnt  + 1
                    return! loop (count)

                | UpdateList  ->
                    //some logic to store list                        
                    sender <! ("Length is " + cnt.ToString())
                    return! loop (0)
            } 
        loop(0)
()
with
|exc -> 
    printfn "%A" exc
```

Agent "A" and "B" are created on same machine but are on different ports.

I have observed that, number of records received by agent B are different each time when I execute above setup.

Means say If I sent 20000 messages to Agent B, Agent B is actually receiving only say 1600(number varies) messages.

What exactly going wrong in above scenario ?

Comment: It's probably impossible to analyze your threading problem from the question's current version. Actors that receive messages in parallel are usually implemented via `MailBoxProcessor<'Msg>`, which doesn't have a method `Tell`. I also don't understand which concept of ports you mean or why they would be relevant. Maybe you could define the actors more clearly, as well as the desired method of synchronization?

Comment: @Vandroiy I think maybe the tag "akka", might be the relevant clue. Though I do agree that some more full source and setup might give some better clue to whats happening anyway...

Comment: @user3146269 http://getakka.net/docs/concepts/message-delivery-reliability might give you a few hints...

Comment: @Vandroiy question is regarding F# Akka.net framework. I have made some corrections in question and also have added some code, you might get some hint from it.

Comment: I don't know if this has anything to do with the issue, but under normal circumstances, you would not manually serialize your message objects in this situation. You just `Tell` a message object to the remote actor, and the Akka framework handles any serialization. In addition, with F# specifically you'll probably get better results configuring Akka remoting to use the Wire serializer rather than JSON.

Comment: In addition, it's generally frowned-upon to send any messages to an ActorSelection - a selection is used to get an actor reference, not in place of an actor reference, as delivery cannot be guaranteed or diagnosed with a Selection. The `ResolveOne` method is one way of getting an actor reference from a selection (which you then re-use).